# Can one automatically append file names with increasing numerical value when copying many files from one directory to another on Mac terminal?

Tags: macos, file, terminal, duplicates, command-line-arguments

I am trying to use a single line command in terminal to find and copy all the files of a certain type in one directory of my computer to another directory. I can do this right now using the below command:

```
find ./ -name '*.fileType' -exec cp -prv '{}' '/destination_directory/' ';'
```

**The problem I'm having is that if a file that is being copied has the same name as a file that was previously copied, it will replace the previously copied file.**

To remedy this, I would like to edit my command such that the files are numbered as they are copied to the new directory.

so the output should look something like this:

**Original Files**

`cat.txt
 dog.txt
 dog.txt`

**Copied Files**

`cat1.txt
 dog2.txt
 dog3.txt`

**Edit:**

The list of commands I can work with are linked here: https://ss64.com/osx/

Specifically for the `cp` command: https://ss64.com/osx/cp.html

-Note: `--backup` and `-b` are not available (it seems) for this version of `cp`

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for the `--backup` option of the `cp` command. E.g.:

```
find ./ -name '*.fileType' -exec cp --backup=t -prv '{}' '/destination_directory/' ';'
```

**Edit:** If you are stuck with MacOS's `cp` you can emulate `--backup`'s behaviour in a script:

```
#!/bin/bash
set -e
# First parameter: source directory   
srcdir=$1
# Second parameter: destination directory
destdir=$2

# Print all filenames separated by '\0' in case you have strange
# characters in the names
find "$srcdir" -type f -print0 |
# Split the input using '\0' as separator and put the current line
# into the $file variable
while read -d $'\0' file; do
  # filename = just the name of the file, without dirs
  filename=$(basename "$file")
  # if destdir does not have a file named filename
  if [ \! -f "$destdir/$filename" ]; then
    cp -pv "$file" "$destdir/$filename";
    continue;
  fi
  # Otherwise
  suffix=1
  # Find the first suffix number that is free
  while [ -f "$destdir/$filename.$suffix" ]; do
    suffix=$(($suffix + 1))
  done
  cp -pv "$file" "$destdir/$filename.$suffix"
done
```

Comment: thanks for your response! I researched the backup command you suggested, and it seems like its on the right track. However, upon testing it out in my terminal, I get an output like this: ```cp: illegal option -- -```

Comment: There may be different versions of `cp`. I assumed you are on some GNU Linux system. The actual options of your version should be described in `man cp`.

Comment: upon using man cp, I got the version of `cp` linked here: https://ss64.com/osx/cp.html This is the version for MacOS. is there a way to achieve the result I want with this version of `cp`?

Comment: I added a workaround to MacOS's `cp` to the solution.

Comment: this looks great! I am just learning about bash scripts. say the type is .jpg, where in this code would I specify that?

Comment: `find` has a lot of options, e.g. `-type f` used in the script selects only regular files (no directories). You can specify a filename pattern adding `-name '*.jpg'` as an option (or the case insensitive equivalent `-iname '*.jpg'`.

Comment: Thank you. Upon running the script, despite working perfectly, it seems as if it loses a lot of permissions relative to the single line command. Why is that? is there a way to remedy this?

Comment: Just add `-prv` to the two `cp` calls in the script.

Comment: after adding `-prv` to the code, am now only getting a mixture of `find: /Users/Guest/**some folder**: Permission denied` and `find: /Users/**my_user_account**/Library/**some folder**: Operation not permitted` I have been running the bash file from my downloads folder (I randomly chose this). when I try to create a bash file in a place like the `/` directory, it says that the file cannot be written. does this mean that the bash file's permissions. also, before running the file, I have been invoking the permission `chmod +x` to give it permission to execute. do I need to add anymore permissions

Comment: You should check some [tutorial on UNIX permissions](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/unix/unix-file-permission.htm). I'll put scripts in `$HOME/bin`. `find` fails because it cannot traverse the directory (lacks the `x` permission). Usually you run backups as root to avoid permission problems.